# Split a pandasframe into X groups each with an average value of Y

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

Really wish I would've paid more attention to statistics in college, maybe I'd remember something for this.

Regardless, I have a dataset with approx ~4800 rows, and I want to group this dataset into 8 groups, however I'd like this final dataset to have only half the rows that the others do (hence 7.5 groups). I would like each of these rows to have approx the same number of rows (except for group 8 which will have 1/2), and the sum of their values equal to approx the same amount.

- Total rows: 4792
- Sum of values: 33367
- Average value per row: 33367/4792=6.963
- Median: 2
- Std Dev: 13.644
- Total rows per intended group: 638.93
- Total rows for 8th group: 319.46
- Total value per intended group: 4448.933
- Total value for 8th group: 2224.4965

I've calculated the following out for the specific dataset and have the formulas ready to calculate them on the fly, but I'm not quite sure how to use Python to split the dataset up. Cursory research into the issue suggests the knapsack algorithm? Other thoughts, set the values of each row to their value - average value, and then take a value from the top and as many values from the bottom until it equals zero, then carry on to next group, repeating through each group, and then starting over, until I've processed through all rows.

Comment: Agreed that this is a knapsack problem. I recommend using `ortools` to help solve it. You can algorithmically figure it out using loops, but it'd be way easier to do so with linear programming.

Comment: @StuSztukowski thanks for the recommendation - I'm looking at the example code Google provides for the module and am a little confused. It mentions needing both weights and values. Are my weights all just equal to 1? Or can weights be used to uniquely identify an item, and thus will allow me to use this packed list as a reference key when sorting my actual items into the proper groups? (I've got a list of dicts I'm dealing with)